# Authorization failure when creating a Stream Analytics job

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I've been trying (and failing) to create an Azure Stream Analytics job programatically. I was following this example originally:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-dotnet-management-sdk/

But it pops up a dialog for you to log in. I want to be able to do this server side. It looks like I need to use Azure AD to use the Resource Manager APIs. I've been working my way through this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx#bk_portal

And the code looks like this:

```cs
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/token");
var clientId = "{app client id}";
var appKey = "{app key}";
var subscriptionId = "{subscription id}";
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

var result = authContext.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential);
var creds = new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, result.AccessToken);

var client = new StreamAnalyticsManagementClient(creds);

var jobCreateParameters = new JobCreateOrUpdateParameters
        {
            Job = new Job
            {
                Name = streamAnalyticsJobName,
                Location = "North Europe",
                Properties = new JobProperties
                {
                    EventsOutOfOrderPolicy = EventsOutOfOrderPolicy.Adjust,
                    Sku = new Sku
                    {
                        Name = "Standard"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

 var jobCreateResponse = client.StreamingJobs.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, jobCreateParameters);
```

I can successfully acquire a token, but creating the job fails:

```
AuthorizationFailed: The client 'REDACTED' with object id 'REDACTED' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/write' over scope '/subscriptions/REDACTED/resourcegroups/REDACTED/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/REDACTED'
```

Am I doing something wrong? The app has the delegated permissions set.

Comment: Have you granted proper permission to your `Service Principal Object`?

Comment: if you mean Step 2 in the 2nd link, then yes

Comment: Apart from this, there's one more step you would need to do (actually there are many more, I too struggled with this) and that is assigning role to the user created for your application in your subscription as `Service Principal`. I would highly recommend that you read this blog post: http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2015/05/23/developers-guide-to-auth-with-azure-resource-manager-api/ and this documentation link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/.

Comment: I started reading that blog post but lost the will to live. I'll take another look, thanks

Comment: LOL :) I had the exact same feeling just a few hours go. Let me try to provide the steps I have taken as an answer.

Comment: that would be fantastic. happy to give you the credit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE - 08-Dec-2015**

There's an easy way to assign roles to Service Principals now. Please see this link for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/.

---

**Original Response**

When you grant access to an application to your Azure subscription, behind the scenes a user is created with `Service Principal` user type in your Azure AD. The code you're using below assumes that you're using this `Service Principal` user when getting access token.

```
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

var result = authContext.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential);
var creds = new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, result.AccessToken);
```

However by default this user is not granted any permissions (RBAC) on your subscription and that's why you're getting the authorization error.

To solve this problem, what you would need to do is grant appropriate role to this user in your subscription. Now you can use [`PowerShell`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/) to do so or you can do it via code using ADAL library + making some web requests.

What I did was I made use of ADAL library to get access tokens and then used `Google Postman` (or `Fiddler`) to do other stuff. In my case, it was a web application. Here's what I did:

1. I logged in into the application as `Global Administrator` (Subscription Owner) and got a `code`. Using that `code` and ADAL library, I got the access token (let's call it `token1`).

   ```
       var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("{0}/common", signinEndpoint));//signinEndpoint = https://login.windows.net
       var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, redirectUri, credential);
   ```
2. I copied the tenant id and access token returned to me in `result` above.
3. Next thing I did was I found out the object id of the `Service Principal` user using POSTMAN. This is the GET URL I executed there. For `Authorization` header, you would need to use `Bearer {token1}`.

   `https://graph.windows.net/{subscription-id}/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.5&$filter=appId eq '{app-client-id}'`
4. After that I acquired another access token (let's call it `token2`) for Service Management API operation using the code below:

   ```
   authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("{0}/{1}", signinEndpoint, result.TenantId));
   result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(serviceManagementApiEndpoint, credential, new UserIdentifier(request.UserInfo.UniqueId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));//serviceManagementApiEndpoint = https://management.core.windows.net/
   ```
5. After that I listed the roles in my subscription and picked the role I wanted to assign to my `Service Principal` user. In my case, I wanted to assign a `Reader` role so I noted down the role's id. For `Authorization` header, you would need to use `Bearer {token2}`.

   `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions?api-version=2015-06-01`
6. Next is assignment of this role to the user. For this I created a guid as `role assignment id` and used the following URL:

   `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleassignments/{role-assignment-id}?api-version=2015-06-01`

It's going to be a `PUT` request and this was the request body would be something like:

```
{
"properties":
    {
        "roleDefinitionId": "{role id of the selected role from step 5}",
        "principalId": "{id of the service principal from step 3"
    }
}
```

Please ensure that the `content-type` of the request is set as `application/json;odata=verbose` and not `application/json`.

That's pretty much it! After that your code should work just fine :)

Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: when I run Get-AzureRoleDefinition, I can't see any role with an action matching "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/write". or have I misunderstood this completely?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in role for this. Please see this link for all built-in roles: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/#built-in-roles.

Comment: ah, thanks! looks like I can create one: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-powershell/#create-a-role-assignment

Comment: This is assigning one of the existing roles to a user (step 6 in my answer). I suggest you try by assigning "Contributor" role for now.

Comment: ah, I didn't see that * in there :) that worked, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a million for the UPDATE - 08-Dec-2015.  That was exactly what I was looking for and took days trying to figure things out.