# Forbidden when passing access token to Azure Service Management (REST)

Tags: c#, rest, azure

I am trying to list all VMs in a Resource Group, according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163572.aspx) API

I have added the application to my AAD tenant, and given it delegated permissions to Windows Azure Service Management Application.

This is my code...

```
private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
private static AuthenticationResult result;
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/<id>.onmicrosoft.com");
    ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    result = ac.AcquireToken("https://management.azure.com/", cc);

    getresponse().Wait();


}
static async Task getresponse()
{

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/resourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines?api-version=2015-05-01-preview");


}
```

(the parts in <> were changed to post here)

At the last line I am getting a 403 forbidden response

Any ideas?!

Comment: why do you have `<subscriptionID>` in your url?

Comment: @Oluwafemi in reality its my subscription id guid, but I changed it to post here (see edit)

Comment: I see. Can you confirm the url is right and the bearer token has not expired.

Comment: @Oluwafemi the URL is the one given in the [API spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163572.aspx) The bearer token is freshly acquired from the third line in main (the client secret is a 1 year expiry that I've just created an hour ago) and the headers are added as per the [API Instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163630.aspx#bk_common)

Comment: but the `subscriptionID` varies so try to confirm its correct and the `{resource-group-name}`

Comment: Have you granted Service Principal of your application access to this Azure Subscription of yours?

Comment: @GauravMantri I have followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx#bk_ad) from step 1 to 8 then taken a client secret and used that in the second line of main - Oluwafemi Resourcegroup name and subscription ID were copied and pasted from the the management console for the VM I'm trying to get information from so it should all tally up to something that exists

Comment: This holds true for your Service Management API requests but what you're doing is fetching the list of VMs using ARM API which has Role-Based access control baked into it. Even though the token is valid but the token is issued to your application and because the application is not granted permission to access the subscription, you're getting this error. Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471828/authorization-failure-when-creating-a-stream-analytics-job/31477009#31477009. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri Of course! that sounds like exactly what it is - I'll confirm and come back - you should post that as an answer...

Comment: Let's first confirm that it is indeed the cause and then I will post my comment as an answer :)

Comment: @GauravMantri That's what it was it, its working now - was the D'oh! moment as soon as I read it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to use Azure Resource Manager (ARM) API using a token acquired for your application however the application does not have access to manage your subscription. What you need to do is assign appropriate role to your application in this subscription.

Please look at my answer to the question here: [Authorization failure when creating a Stream Analytics job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471828/authorization-failure-when-creating-a-stream-analytics-job) where I have described two ways by which you can assign a role to your application.

Comment: As part of poking around in this, I realised that Azure does automatically create a Service Principle from applications, but it is hidden from the normal AD view. when you add a user permission to a resource, you can search for application names and add them directly (no coding - or PS - needed!)

Comment: The answer, in the link of the answer above is the answer and has been a savior:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/